# Java Jersey register Multipart for uplaod file service - ERR: No meesage body reader has been found

Tags: java, rest, upload, jersey, multipart

I'm new to RESTful services and Jersey. I'm trying to create a ws that respond to POST call with enctype mutipart/form-data.

First of all I have my application Class

```
import com.ibm.sampleapp.rest.ConversationWS;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class WinkApplication extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
enter code here
    // Returns the list of classes which are to be added as REST endpoints
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
    classes.add(FormDataContentDisposition.class);
    classes.add(RESTws.class);
    return classes;
}
```

and then I have my rest service class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@Path("")
public class RESTws extends ResourceConfig {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception {

    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
    resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    resourceConfig.register(FormDataContentDisposition.class);

    String filename = fileMetaData.getFileName();


    String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\$User\\Doc\\" + filename;
    try {
         saveFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
         return Response.status(400).entity(e.getCause()).build();
    }

    String output = "File uploaded to: " + uploadedFileLocation;

    System.out.println("File uploaded..");
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    // save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String serverLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Finally i have the index.html in which i upload the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Java Web Starter Application</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>


<h1>RESTful Web Service - File Upload Example</h1>  
<form action="http://localhost:9080/java-sample-backend/api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<p>  
    Select a file to Upload to server: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" />  
</p>  
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />  
</form>  


</body>
</html>
```

My dependencies are:

```
 <!-- Jersey -->       
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to upload a file trough my html i get the following error:

> [ERROR   ] No message body reader has been found for class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------------7e21f97403c2

Googling around the issue I understand that my problem is that I do not have my service registered, but I can not understand how I can achieve it.

Is there a way to do it programmatically and not via web.xml file?
 -
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class like `MyRestApplication extends ResourceConfig` that is annotated with `@ApplicationPath("/PATH")`. In the constructor of this class you call `register( MultiPartFeature.class );` and register your service classes using `registerClasses( MyService.class );`.

The class `MyService` does not extend any other class but must be annotated by `@Path("/SERVICEPATH")`. This class then contains method `uploadFile`.

You don't need a `web.xml`.

Comment: Hi braunpet and thanks for your response. I have my class 
`@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {


 public JerseyConfig() {
  
 // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
        packages("com.ibm.sampleapp.rest");
  register(MultiPartFeature.class);registerClasses(MyService.class);}`

But still receiving [ERROR   ] No message body reader has been found for class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, Conte..
[WARNING ] javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: I've tested the suggested backend code and (your) frontend code in one of my projects successfully. Can you please edit or extend your question showing the backend code (class `MyService`) that you are using now. And please check that you are using the same Jersey version (`2.22.1` in your example) for all libraries. For `jersey-media-multipart` you are using an older one right now.

Comment: I think the problem was in wrong versions of the libraries. I was really confused about that and how to properly use them. After few days trying to solve the issue I solved it registering servlet and CORSfilter by web.xml.
In my case this just solved the problem. The next time that I have to implement this I will try again with ResourceConfig. The source code actually is pretty big and have changed a lot . Thank you very much for the help guys!